# How to reload stale external google maps api javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-chrome, google-maps-api-3, google-chrome-extension

So we have a chrome extension and the background.html looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>

  <script id="google-maps-js" type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&key=AIzaSyCnHJh2lsVbM_fPXgwciRO-fInFgkkEebw&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/background_helper.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/background.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The google maps api js is loaded once when the extension is installed or when the browser is first opened but if the browser is left open for more than 3 days, the geocoder service starts to return 403 errors and I believe it's related to the problem mentioned in the answer to this question:

[After months of 100% stability, today I get 403 Error on google maps services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10719319/after-months-of-100-stability-today-i-get-403-error-on-google-maps-services)

It seems that after 3 days, the javascript becomes 'stale' and google will return 403 errors to any requests. 
I tried putting in a timer so that every 24 hours it removes the google maps script tag and reads it but then I get errors saying I've included the google maps script multiple times and it will behave unexpectedly.

How do I "reload" or "refresh" the javascript so it's no longer stale?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply manipulate the `<script>` element.

Delete it from the DOM by id, and insert an identical copy. That will re-run the script, and the server should be configured to disallow caching if it is indeed getting stale.