# Android: Getting HTTP 403 Forbidden upon calling https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml

Tags: java, android, web-services, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've developed an Android Application since 2012. Since now I've made use of the free web service api v3 for geocoding without an API key so that we have a limit of 2,500 request per IP and not for KEY without problems:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml

All has worked fine until this period when sometimes some of my users soffers of error 403 - Forbidden during this web server call.

Has Google Changed something for the use of his webservices?

Eventually I could use the Geocoder class of the Android Framework.

But I've still another webservice that i call:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml

Could also this webservice suffer of the 403 error? Up to now I don't know because if I get 403 error in geocode I won't call the direction webservice.

Comment: Interesting I might say. I was going to say if your using version 2, that was depreciated, but that's not the case.

Comment: Could you post your URL you are using?

Comment: Here is an example: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Corso%20Garibaldi%206,%2000060,%20,%20ROMA%2000060%20B,%20ITALIA&sensor=true&language=IT
It works fine for me, but sometimes users are suffering 403 error. I don't think to exceed the quota limit becouse without a key is limited by IP.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little information you may want to look over... You can find more about this [**here**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/articles/usage_limits).

> **HTTP 403 response**
>
> Requests to the web services may also receive a HTTP 403 (Forbidden)
>   error. In most cases, this is due to an invalid URL signature. To
>   verify this, remove the client and signature parameters and try again:
>
> If the response is HTTP 200 (OK), the signature was the problem.  This
>   is not related to usage limits; see Troubleshooting authentication
>   issues in the Web Services chapter of the Google Maps API for Work
>   documentation for details. If the response is still a HTTP 403
>   (Forbidden) error, the signature was not necessarily the problem, it
>   may be related to usage limits instead.  This typically means your
>   access to the web service has been blocked on the grounds that your
>   application has been exceeding usage limits for too long or otherwise
>   abused the web service. Please contact Google Enterprise Support if
>   you encounter this issue. Requests to all web services require URL
>   signatures. Requests will also be rejected with a HTTP 403 (Forbidden)
>   error when including the client parameter but missing the signature
>   parameter, or vice versa.
>
> **Problems**
>
> You can exceed the Google Maps API Web Services usage limits by:
>
> Sending too many requests per day. Sending requests too fast, i.e. too
>   many requests per second. Sending requests too fast for too long or
>   otherwise abusing the web service. Exceeding other usage limits, e.g.
>   points per request in the Elevation API.
>
> **Solutions**
>
> The above problems can be address by combining two approaches:
>
> Lowering usage, by optimizing applications to use the web services
>   more efficiently. Increasing usage limits, when possible, by
>   purchasing additional allowance for your Google Maps API for Work
>   license. This article will focus on ways of optimizing applications to
>   use the web services more efficiently.

Here's [**another**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10719319/after-months-of-100-stability-today-i-get-403-error-on-google-maps-services) good link that may just help as well.

Comment: These are all things I've already read but I don't think a single user can exceed the quota limit per IP (2,500 request/day). And the application make only 1 request per address so It's quite impossible to make more requests per second.